# How to achieve Post-Redirect-Get in a Wordpress plugin's admin menu page?

Tags: redirect, wordpress, post-redirect-get

I am writing a Wordpress plugin, which adds an admin menu page. In the page is a form. When the form is submitted, the plugin writes to the database. But then I encounter a problem: whenever the user reloads the page, he/she is asked whether to send the POSTDATA again. If the user clicks yes, the plugin writes to the database again.

After some searching, I found a solution, the "Post-Redirect-Get" pattern.
Then, later, I found that it's hard to implement this pattern into a Wordpress plugin.

1. The plugin itself cannot send an HTTP 301/302 because there are some contents already outputted by the Wordpress core.
2. It is possible to insert a meta tag (in order to issue a redirect) in the HTML head. But according to W3C, meta redirect is deprecated, so I think it's better not to use it.
3. Use JavaScript's `window.location`. But what if JavaScript is disabled in the user's browser?

Is there any other way to achieve redirection?

Comment: +1 for caring about Post-Redirect-Get...something 90% of wordpress developers problem have probably never heard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try doing your plugin's processing in the `admin_init` hook, which, I believe, is run before any content is output.

Comment: +1. Hooking into an early action like `admin_init` is the way to go. Also a good idea to use the `wp_redirect` function.

Answer (score 2):

To save a LOT of work.  Just use the WordPress settings api.

Codex article -> [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

More helpful article by Otto -> [here](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/)

Using the WordPress settings api will take care of the "Post-Redirect-Get" issue you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

1. check if table exist in the data base or insert in sql if not
   exists for not action if the table exists in the data base.
2. option is set_option where plugin is activated.
3. use register_activation_hook wordpress function for include
   options plugin activate

sorry for my english, is very bad, but I think you can understand